# Why does Philae have only three legs?

Tags: rocket-science, solar-system-exploration

Can anyone explain why comet lander [Philae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philae_(spacecraft)) has only three legs? Isn't it obvious that it now has problems that it would not have had if it had four legs arranged as a [**regular** tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) - or even more legs? Were legs so expensive?

Comment: have a look What geometry concept can be used to explain this?

"The reason actually lies in the fact that it only takes three points to define a plane. Any point that is added to that plane will make it harder and harder for the plane to be stable." http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~wanous/part3.html

Comment: We are not talking about something like a plane underground with strong gravitational effects - but about an unpredictabily irregular underground with some soft gravitational effects.

Comment: Why does a tripod have only 3 legs?

Comment: @Prahar: haha! See my comment above. (On an irregular surface with low gravitational forces the tripod example doesn't help further.)

Comment: Now that the question has been clarified (see Hans' comment to my answer), he is asking about adding a fourth leg pointing upward so that the vehicle would be stable regardless of orientation.

Comment: @HansStricker, please ask the question you want to ask. Don't beat around the bush; we can't read your mind. What would the orientation of this fourth leg be with respect to the existing legs, and why do you foresee a benefit?

Comment: I DID explain what the orientation of the fourth leg should be: by "(regular) tetrahedron". Foreseen benefit: more stability.

Comment: How exactly does this fourth leg add stability? You are positing something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @David: Thanks for your re-(in)queries. Now I see things better.

Comment: How do you arrange 4 legs in a regular tetrahedron = triangular pyramid which has 3 edges meeting at a point?

Answer (score 4):

Have you ever sat on a wobbly, four-legged chair? That can't happen with a three-legged chair. A three-legged chair is stable. Four legs is one leg too many. A four-legged lander would need to adjust the lengths of the legs to stabilize it.

**Update**
Aside: The English word you are seeking is tetrahedron. Now that the intent of the question is clear, the answer is **no**. Adding a fourth leg to Philae so it could land in any orientation wouldn't work because Philae has a preferred orientation. There would be no point in adding the capability to land in some other orientation because many of the experiments on the wouldn't be able to function. Philae has a definite "up" and "down".

**Second update**
A tetrahedral object can land in four different orientations. Only one of those orientations is useful because Philae has a definite "up" and "down". There would be no point in adding a fourth tetrahedral leg without the ability to reorient the central body of the vehicle. That adds considerable complexity to the vehicle.

The reason Philae had problems was because its simple harpoon system and its simple thruster system failed. BTW, those harpoons and that thruster were part of what gave Philae a definite "up" and "down". As was seen with Philae, even simple stuff has an unfortunately high propensity to fail in spacecraft. Complex stuff? That fails with even greater propensity. Spacecraft designers have learned this lesson many times over and regularly have to tell themselves to "keep it simple, stupid!" The [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) is driving concept in designing space vehicles.

Comment: The question was not about four legs as a table has, but about tetrahedron-shaped four-legged object, like methane molecule (with hydrogen atoms as legs).

Comment: We are not talking about something like a plane underground with strong gravitational effects - but about an unpredictabily irregular underground with some soft gravitational effects.

Comment: @David: But now one of the three legs rises helplessly into the air. Wouldn't it be better that a fourth leg touches ground? In any case? (Left alone of what you explained - which I hope to have understood.)

Comment: @HansStricker -- I haven't the foggiest idea what you mean by that, or why you would think that extra legs would help solve that problem. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Does this mean: the best one can do is to give a lander three legs? (Because we live in three dimensions.) I claim: this is not sooo obvious.

Comment: Four legs and a gimbal, perhaps? That's not unlike the "air bags" used on some Mars missions - but probably needlessly expensive (mass to carry billions of miles). Then again, flipping over is expensive too...

Comment: @Floris -- And that gimbal would be yet another thing that can fail. YAGNI! (You Ain't Gonna Need It)

Comment: Yes - I wrote that comment at the same time you were writing your KISS update - "... adds considerable complexity..."

Comment: The harpoon system is somehow clear to me: "inject the harpoon wherever it finds ground and appropriate conditions" - but how does this ominous thruster system work?

Comment: @HansStricker -- Think of Newton's third law. When the spacecraft fires the harpoons, the harpoons go down, but the spacecraft goes up in response. That equal but opposite reaction is not desired. The thruster was intended to counteract that undesired reaction. It was supposed to fire upward, forcing the vehicle to stay in contact with the surface while the harpoons drilled into the surface.

Comment: @HansStricker See http://space.stackexchange.com/a/2243/6005. I haven't checked the calc but presume the space buffs would have done so - note that the escape velocity from 67P is of the order of *one metre per second*. That's not much of a nudge  that you must stay beneath before the mission (Philae's at least) is all over.

Comment: a second reason that a definite orientation is needed is the sun. It is supposed to recharge with photovoltaics, no good if they end up underneath.